# SignalR recording when a Web Page has closed

Tags: signalr

I am using MassTransit request and response with SignalR. The web site makes a request to a windows service that creates a file. When the file has been created the windows service will send a response message back to the web site. The web site will open the file and make it available for the users to see. I want to handle the scenario where the user closes the web page before the file is created. In that case I want the created file to be emailed to them.

Regardless of whether the user has closed the web page or not, the message handler for the response message will be run. What I want to be able to do is have some way of knowing within the response message handler that the web page has been closed. This is what I have done already. It doesnt work but it does illustrate my thinking. On the web page I have

```
$(window).unload(function () {
            if (event.clientY < 0) {
                // $.connection.hub.stop();
                $.connection.exportcreate.setIsDisconnected();
    }
});
```

exportcreate is my Hub name. In setIsDisconnected would I set a property on Caller? Lets say I successfully set a property to indicate that the web page has been closed. How do I find out that value in the response message handler. This is what it does now

```
    protected void BasicResponseHandler(BasicResponse message)
    {
        string groupName = CorrelationIdGroupName(message.CorrelationId);

        GetClients()[groupName].display(message.ExportGuid);
    }

    private static dynamic GetClients()
    {
        return AspNetHost.DependencyResolver.Resolve<IConnectionManager>().GetClients<ExportCreateHub>();
    }
```

I am using the message correlation id as a group. Now for me the ExportGuid on the message is very important. That is used to identify the file. So if I am going to email the created file I have to do it within the response handler because I need the ExportGuid value. If I did store a value on Caller in my hub for the web page close, how would I access it in the response handler.

Just in case you need to know. display is defined on the web page as

```
            exportCreate.display = function (guid) {
                setTimeout(function () {
                    top.location.href = 'GetExport.ashx?guid=' + guid;
                }, 500);
            };
```

GetExport.ashx opens the file and returns it as a response.

Thank you,

Regards Ben

Answer (score 3):

I think a better bet would be to implement proper connection handling. Specifically, have your hub implementing IDisconnect and IConnected. You would then have a mapping of connectionId to document Guid.

```
    public Task Connect()
    {
        connectionManager.MapConnectionToUser(Context.ConnectionId, Context.User.Name);
    }

    public Task Disconnect()
    {
        var connectionId = Context.ConnectionId;
        var docId = connectionManager.LookupDocumentId(connectionId);
        if (docId != Guid.Empty) 
        {
           var userName = connectionManager.GetUserFromConnectionId(connectionId);
           var user = userRepository.GetUserByUserName(userName);
           bus.Publish( new EmailDocumentToUserCommand(docId, user.Email));
        }
    }

    // Call from client
    public void GenerateDocument(ClientParameters docParameters) 
    {
        var docId = Guid.NewGuid();
        connectionManager.MapDocumentIdToConnection(Context.ConnectionId, docId);
        var command = new CreateDocumentCommand(docParameters);
        command.Correlationid = docId;
        bus.Publish(command);
        Caller.creatingDocument(docId);
    }

    // Acknowledge you got the doc.
    // Call this from the display method on the client.
    // If this is not called, the disconnect method will handle sending
    // by email.
    public void Ack(Guid docId) 
    {          
       connectionManager.UnmapDocumentFromConnectionId(connectionId, docId);
       Caller.sendMessage("ok");
    }
```

Of course this is from the top of my head.